# How to use Kotlin generics to access same fields in sibling classes

Tags: kotlin, generics, inheritance, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

```
data class Type1(val str: String)
data class Type2(val str: String)

interface Person

data class Child1(val name: Type1) : Person
data class Child2(val name: Type2) : Person

fun main() {
    val foo = Child1(Type1("foo"))
    val bar = Child2(Type2("bar"))

    printName(foo)
    printName(bar)
}
    
fun printName(person: Person) {

    // Option 1: would like to do this
    // println(person.name)  // Unresolved reference: name

    // Option 2: works but if I have lots of other code,
    //   it's unnecessary duplication of code
    when (person) {
        is Child1 -> {
            println(person.name)
            // lots of other code
        }
        is Child2 -> {
            println(person.name)
            // lots of other code
        }
    }
}
```

Inside printName(), I would like to be able to use a single println(person.name) call and have it print the name of either Child1 or Child2, whichever is passed in. What are the different ways I can make this happen in Kotlin?

UPDATE:

1. I don't own the base classes so not able to change the inheritance.
2. The names of each child are of different types.

Comment: Adding `val name: String` to the `Person` interface and overriding it in the `Child` classes seems like an obvious solution. Is there any reason why you can't do that?

Comment: I don't own those classes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `name` in your interface, like

```
interface Person {
    val name: String
}

data class Child1(override val name: String) : Person

data class Child2(override val name: String) : Person
```

to be able to get it from other Child classes...

If not every child class that extends Person will contain name, you can introduce an intermediate interface, like

```
interface Person

interface NamedPerson : Person {
    val name: String
}

data class Child1(override val name: String) : NamedPerson

data class Child2(override val name: String) : NamedPerson
```

In any other case, there should be an instance check, like

```
   when (person) {
        is Child1 -> println(person.name)
        is Child2 -> println(person.name)
    }
```

Comment: I don't own those classes so can't change them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension function if you don't own those classes

```kotlin
data class Type1(val str: String)
data class Type2(val str: String)

interface Person

data class Child1(val name: Type1) : Person

data class Child2(val name: Type2) : Person

// extension
fun Person.getNameStr() : String {
    return when(this){
        is Child1 -> name.str
        is Child2 -> name.str
        else -> ""
    }
}

// or

val Person.nameStr : String
    get() = when(this){
        is Child1 -> name.str
        is Child2 -> name.str
        else -> ""
    }

fun printName(person: Person) {
    println(person.getNameStr())
    //or
    println(person.nameStr)
}
```

**Importance**

**this extension will not valid if you want to return the class itself (`Type1` and `Type2`)**

Comment: Sorry, the child names are actually of different types, not the same String type. I'll update my question.

Comment: @awardak are those `type1` and `type2` inherit from same class/interface ??

Comment: No, they don't.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I do need `Type1` and `Type2`.